# How to create multiple overlapping views in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have seen in some google apps that they have a floating action button over the center of a line.
I have been trying to implement multiple overlapping images over a linealayout.
[image]

As you can see from the image, two boxes represent linear layouts and the circles are the images on the center of the lines.

How can we achieve this ?

Comment: both the LinearLayout should be in Relative Layout, you can then use align properties of Relative Layout to create overlaping effects

Comment: Look at - http://davehiren.blogspot.in/2014/04/android-use-framelayout-for-overlapping.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try different combinations of `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayouts`. Here is an example for you;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this example there are two `LinearLayout`s that overlap each other. One of them is used for the contents and the second one is used for overlapping buttons. And by `weight` and `gravity` properties, I adjusted them to look like what you wanted. Just try this code!! It looks like;

[image]